# python regular expression find text between tags but the file is not in html or xml format

Tags: python

I have a text file which has the format below, and I am trying to get the text between the `<doc>` tags. But the `<doc>` tags repeat many times and the file is not in a standard xml or html format, and this causes a problem.

Format:

`<doc id = "some_number" url = " some_link " title = " some_title " >`

`text here`

`</doc>` //then again

`<doc id = "some_number" url = " some_link " title = " some_title " >`

`text here`

`</doc>`  // and so on

I tried to get the text using Beautiful soup in python but it said that this object is not callable, and I am guessing it is because it is not in html file format. Moreover I tried using regular expressions so I wrote

`pattern = re.compile("<doc.*?>(.*?)</doc>")`

`pattern.findall(string_text) # string_text is my file`

but no match is found.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it tells you "this object is not callable", you're clearly using `BeautifulSoup` wrong, not just giving it invalid data. Show us the actual code that you tried, and the actual error you got, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Which object is not callable? What gave you the error in BS4?

Comment: Also, what makes you think that your text file isn't valid HTML? The sample you've given here looks valid, and every parser I throw at it handles it with no problem.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're asking how to parse HTML with regexps, and you haven't read [Don't Parse HTML with Regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), go read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing visibly wrong with your HTML, and no reason BeautifulSoup shouldn't be able to parse it. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<doc id = "some_number" url = " some_link " title = " some_title " >

text here

</doc>

<doc id = "some_number" url = " some_link " title = " some_title " >

text here

</doc>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
for doc in soup.find_all('doc'):
    print('{}: {}'.format(doc['title'], doc.text))
```

When I run this, here's what it displays:

```
 some_title :
text here

 some_title :
text here
```

It also works if I leave in the C++-style comments that you had in your question, but had outside the code sections.

---

If "it said that this object is not callable", you've obviously done something wrong with your code. For example, if I do this:

```
for doc in soup.find_all('doc'):
    doc['title']('text')
```

… it will of course raise:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

But that's not because BS couldn't parse the HTML, it's because I got a string out of BS and tried to call it as a function.

I have no idea what *you* actually did wrong, because you haven't shown us the code, or even the exact error that you got.

---

Meanwhile, if you're wondering what's wrong with your HTML, there are three problems.

The first problem is that [You can't parse HTML with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

The second problem is that you're trying to use `.*?` to match, among other things, newlines, and right near the very top of the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) docs, it says:

> `'.'`
>
> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

So, you need `pattern = re.compile("<doc.*?>(.*?)</doc>", re.DOTALL)`.

However, if a `doc` can have another `doc` inside, or if you can have any characters inside quotes that will confuse you, or if… well, there are a lot of reasons this can fail. Which is why:

The third problem is that you didn't read [You can't parse HTML with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and you need to go read it.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_doc = """
         <doc id = "some_number" url = " some_link " title = " some_title " >
         text here
         </doc> //then again

         <doc id = "some_number" url = " some_link " title = " some_title " >
         text here
         </doc>
         """
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

soup = b(your_doc)

specific_doc = b.find('doc', {'id': 'some number'}) #to get a doc with given id. 
print specific_doc.contents #printing the text

all_docs = b.findAll('docs') # list of all doc tags.
for doc in all_docs: #printing all the texts
    print 'Text in doc id:', doc['id']
    print doc.contents
```